# ES2015 + ES2016 (decorators, comprehensions, ...) + Angular 1.x Components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm working on a web app architecture with Angular 1.x still used to glue things together. Defining a new component is fairly easy:

```es2015
class CustomComponent {
  constructor(dep1, dep2, dep3) {
    this.deps = { dep1, dep2, dep3 };
    /* app code */
  }

  /* link, compile, instance methods, template generators... */

  @readonly static $inject = ['dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3'];
}
```

What I'd like to do is factor out injection concerns - in other words, I'd like not to write `this.deps` and `static $inject` code every time, but rather have it auto-generated - say, with something like decorators in ES7. The code would then look something along the following lines:

```es2015
@injectionFromCtorComponents
class MyClass {
  constructor (dep1, dep2, dep3) {
    /* app logic */
  }
}
```

Now, the static part is doable, albeit ugly:

```es2015
const angularInjectAnnotationFromCtor = (target) => {
    let regexStr = `^function ${target.name}\\\((.*)\\\)[.\\s\\S]*}$`;
    let regex = new RegExp(regexStr, 'gm');
    let ctorArgsStr = target.prototype.constructor.toString().replace(regex, '\$1');
    let ctorArgs = ctorArgsStr.replace(/ /g, '').split(',');

    target.$inject = ctorArgs;
};
```

The saving of constructor dependencies on the instance, though, is much trickier. I came up with the following, although it's flimsy at best:

```es2015
const readonly = (target, key, descriptor) => Object.assign(descriptor, { writable: false });

class AngularComponent {
  constructor () {
    let ctorArgs = [...arguments];
    let argNames = ctorArgs.pop();

    // let's leave comprehensions out of this :)
    this.deps = 
      argNames.reduce((result, arg, idx) => Object.assign(result, ({ [arg]: ctorArgs[idx] })), {});
  }
}

@angularInjectAnnotationFromCtor
class MyClass extends AngularComponent {
    constructor (one, two, three) {
      super(one, two, three, MyClass.$inject);
    }
}
```

Yeah, this is worse than where we started...

So the questions is then, could anyone suggest a more reasonable solution to this?.. Or should we simply sit back and hope for Proxies in Chrome anytime within the next couple of years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static part of your idea is basically like not having `$inject` at all. It's pointless.

I suggest to forget the idea or pass arguments to the decorator:

```
@inject('dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3')
class MyClass {
  constructor (dep1, dep2, dep3) {
    /* app logic */
  }
}
```

The constructor part could be done using the classical decorator pattern:

```
function inject() {
  var dependencies = [...arguments];

  return function decorator(target) {
    target.$inject = dependencies;  

    return function() {
      this.deps = {};
      dependencies.forEach((dep, index) => {
        this.deps[dep] = arguments[index];
      });

      target.constructor.apply(arguments, this);
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't understand the first sentence, though - why pointless? why like not having at all?..

Comment: @IlyaAyzenshtok Angular can get the dependencies from the constructor itself. The point of an explicitely defined `$inject` is to have strings that don't get lost by minification. So basically you are trying to do what Angular already does.

Comment: The point is to create minification-safe code without framework-specific explicit ceremony. The static ```$inject``` decorator would do just that - produce code that can be safely minified, with Angular issues taken care of. But otherwise, great answer, thank you! I somehow missed the fact that a class decorator can also return something.